# How to secure and recover a multisignature wallet

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, solidity-0.8.x, multisignature

I am creating an erc-20 token which funds will be managed by some board members using MultiSig wallet/contract. Let's say I have 5 members and 3 out of 5 votes is enough to manage funds. What happpens if 3 of the private keys or members are lost. What is the best way/precaution to recover from this.

Answer (score 2):

> What happpens if 3 of the private keys or members are lost.

You are screwed.

> What is the best way/precaution to recover from this.

- Have more members
- Make sure all members have paper backups of their keys
- Have better members that do not lose their keys